# Unable to initialize SelectList in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm struggling with an ASP.NET MVC app. Currently, I'm trying to just get a checkbox list to work. In an attempt to do this, I was using this [blog post](http://benfoster.io/blog/checkbox-lists-in-aspnet-mvc). I feel like I'm close. However, for some reason, all of my checkbox list items display `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`. I do not understand why. My model code looks like this:

```
public SelectList AvailableTypeList { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedTypes { get; set; }

public void Initialize()
{
  List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
  foreach (var availableType in await AvailableType.LoadFromDatabaseAsync())
  {
    SelectListItem listItem = new SelectListItem
    {
      Text = availableType.Name,
      Value = availableType.Id.ToString()
    };
    items.Add(listItem);
  }
  AvailableTypeList = new SelectList(items);

  int i = 0;
}
```

I have two breakpoints. One set at the line that says `items.Add(listItem)` and another at `int i = 0;`.

When the first breakpoint trips, the `Text` and `Value` properties are exactly what I'd expect. However, when the second breakpoint trips, I notice in the watch window that `AvailableTypeList .FirstOrDefault().Text` is "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem". Why?

I do not understand why the `Text` and `Value` properties of the `SelectListItem` objects are being reset. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't told the SelectList what property to display for Text, so it is calling the ToString() method of the underlying item.  Set AvailableTypeList.DataTextField = "Text", then you should see what you expect.  You'll need to do the same for the DataValueField.

Comment: Why on earth would your create `List<SelectListItem>` then convert it to `SelectList` (which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) and pass it to `DropDownListFor()` which expects `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I notice in the watch window that AvailableTypeList
>   .FirstOrDefault().Text is "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem". Why?

Here,

```
SelectListItem listItem = new SelectListItem
{
  Text = availableType.Name,
  Value = availableType.Id.ToString()
};
```

public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField
)
you create an object of type `listItem` and then here:

```
 items.Add(listItem);
```

you add it in a list of `SelectListItem` objcets.

On the other hand, in the following line:

```
AvailableTypeList = new SelectList(items);
```

You create a new `SelectList` object using the items. In the `SelectList` the items that are in your list will be appended in the `SelectList`. Since the type of objects in the items is `SelectListItem`, this would be the type of items int the `SelectList` you create.

Specifically, you used the following constructor of the `SelectList`:

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items)
```

which as it is stated in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492864(v=vs.118).aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the
>   specified items for the list.

Regarding this:

> I do not understand why the Text and Value properties of the
>   SelectListItem objects are being reset. What am I doing wrong? Thank
>   you SO much for any help you can provide.

This is happening, because you don't use the correct constructor, which is the following:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField
)
```

You have to state explicitly, which is the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField`. If you use the above, like below:

```
AvailableTypeList = new SelectList(items,"Value","Text");
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for the details. I appreciate the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Create it with an item:

```
SelectList docs = new SelectList(new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "Please Select...", Value = "error", Selected = true } });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer

Comment: It's in case you want to initialize a dropdownlist or show it empty